# The freeswitch gateway is not created

Tags: debian, voip, freeswitch

In addition to the fact that the gateway is not visible after processing commands, the files with settings of already existing gateways in the same folders are not visible.

```
$ nano /etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles/external/domru.xml

<include>
        <gateway name="domru_2252800">
                <param name="username" value="70000000000"/>
                <param name="password" value="PASSWORD"/>
                <param name="realm" value="voip.domru.ru"/>
                <param name="from-user" value="70000000000"/>
                <param name="from-domain" value="voip.domru.ru"/>
                <param name="proxy" value="voip.domru.ru:5060"/>
                <param name="expire-seconds" value="800"/>
                <param name="register" value="true"/>
                <param name="register-transport" value="udp"/>
                <param name="retry-seconds" value="60"/>
                <param name="context" value="public"/>
                <param name="caller-id-in-from" value="false"/>
        </gateway>
</include>
```

Save

```
$ fs_cli
freeswitch@fusionpbx> sofia profile external rescan reloadxml
freeswitch@fusionpbx> sofia status
                     Name          Type                                       Data      State
=================================================================================================
            external-ipv6       profile                   sip:mod_sofia@[::1]:5080      RUNNING (0)
                 external       profile             sip:mod_sofia@172.22.1.25:5080      RUNNING (0)
external::593c9adc-85e8-4245-a223-11f344945d57  gateway                        sip:1024@10.3.22.10      REGED
external::9561bdbb-60e9-4eb5-8d62-5399e48d6850  gateway                        sip:1022@10.3.22.10      REGED
external::9cd3fb9e-a4a7-40b0-b419-bfb8141ab758  gateway                        sip:1009@10.3.22.10      REGED
external::e3f98f4c-1270-4820-b786-77dbcb5255d7  gateway                        sip:1017@10.3.22.10      REGED
external::e108b58a-d018-4c26-be2f-b1d9f4628f35  gateway                        sip:1306@10.3.22.10      REGED
external::3338e692-7ea3-4845-ad43-476663eb2ef8  gateway                        sip:1307@10.3.22.10      REGED
external::69a12109-a2b5-4a19-915f-46d779d9f633  gateway                        sip:1032@10.3.22.10      REGED
external::f5a0fb27-c4e2-44a2-88d7-ba66e278e4da  gateway                        sip:1030@10.3.22.10      REGED
external::29a522d2-ed65-463f-8b5e-67497e31131f  gateway                        sip:1029@10.3.22.10      REGED
external::3600d3ce-b5d3-47ad-9ef6-527f94b70cce  gateway                        sip:1027@10.3.22.10      REGED
            internal-ipv6       profile                   sip:mod_sofia@[::1]:5060      RUNNING (0)
                 internal       profile             sip:mod_sofia@172.22.1.25:5060      RUNNING (0)
=================================================================================================
4 profiles 0 aliases
```

How and where to correctly set the settings for adding a gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using fusionpbx settings are stored in the database. To configure the PBX, you only need to use the GUI.